# how to add custom value to selectlist in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want Add "Select Activity" values as first values of HTML dropdown, but when I add it is showing as last record in Drop down.

I want to show Default value as "Select Activity" in drop down.

I am using ASP.NET MVC3, code:

```
public SelectList GetSubContractorechniciansList(String subContractorId)
{
    var s1 = GetSubContractorechnicians(subContractorId);
    var result = s1.ToList().Select(d => new
    {
        Key = d.TECH_NUMBER,
        Value = d.EMPLOYEE_TECH_NAME.ToString()
    }).Distinct().ToDictionary(mc => mc.Key, mc => mc.Value);
    result.Add("Select Activity", "Select Activity");
    var selectItems = new SelectList(result, "Key", "Value");            
    return selectItems;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this when rendering the dropdown in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SomeModelProperty, Model.Items, "Select Activity")
```

or if against all good practices you don't use a view model and rely on weakly typed ViewBag and helpers:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Items, "Select Activity")
```

Comment: Html.DropDownList("ddl"+ item.Activity_Number.ToString(),

Comment: please see my original post i added my View code for dropdown control, and sugget me

Comment: @user581007, if this post helped you solve the problem please [mark it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - How do we assign a numeric value to the default text? Something like a 0?

Comment: @renegadeMind, you can't and this doesn't make sense. A default value for something that is not selected logically must be an empty string. That's what the Html.DropDownListFor helper does out of the box and you cannot modify this behavior. It is by design. If for some unknown reason you want to use 0 as default value you will have to write your own helper as this doesn't follow conventions.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Well i want this so that i can follow conventions. A value in the dropdown should be a number rather than a blank string even if its empty.

Comment: @renegadeMind, no, you are wrong. If you allow for empty values in your dropdown you shouldn't be using the `int` datatype on your view model at all. It doesn't make sense to use a value type for something that doesn't have a value such as when the user hasn't yet selected any element. You should use `int?` (`Nullable<int>`) on your view model in this case.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I hear you and that i what i am currently doing; i am just trying to achieve what was possible in webforms - maybe this is not possible in MVC!

Comment: @renegadeMind, ASP.NET MVC and classic WebForms are actually 2 very different ways to write web applications. They follow different rules and conventions. The end result to the user is of course the same but the way to achieve this end result is pretty different.